# How to retrieve data from postgresql jsonb column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a data like this store in postgres jsonb column - `{"purpose_of_name":"official","surname":"Donald","first_name":"Duck"}`.  json element can be changed like more or less . How can I retrieve data something like this

```
purpose_of_name| surname| first_name
----------+----------+--------------------
   official|       Donald |  Duck
```

And if there is more element

```
{"purpose_of_name":"official","surname":"Donald","first_name":"Duck", "last_name" :"Treat"}
```

```
purpose_of_name| surname| first_name| last_name
----------+----------+--------------------
   official|       Donald |  Duck | Treat
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table name is 'users' and jsonb column is 'settings', the query can be written as:

```
SELECT
  settings->>'purpose_of_name' AS purpose_of_name
  settings->>'surname' AS surname
  settings->>'first_name' AS first_name
  settings->>'last_name' AS last_name
FROM users;
```